# Data access from Postgresql to node/express: resp.rows[0] is undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, dao

I am using node and express on this project, and am having issues with collecting the data from the database and putting the data into an object called User.

What mistake am I making to prevent the sql data from being put into resp.rows[0]?

I have done a few "tests" like run console.log(resp); and console.log(resp.rows[0]);. Both confirm that resp.rows[0] is empty and undefined. And I am unsure why, as I have gotten a few of these to work already just fine.

Just for reference, this one is working:

```
//retrieve all users export async function getAllUsers(): Promise<User[] | any>{     
const client=await pool.connect();     
try {         
    const resp= await client.query(`             
    SELECT account_id, username, password_hash, email, account_type_id 
    FROM account             
`);          
const users: User[] = [];         
resp.rows.forEach((userResult: SqlUser) => {                                         console.log(userResult);                             users.push(userConverter(userResult))         
});         
    return users;     
} catch (error) {         
    console.log(error);         
    //return error.message;     
} finally {         
    client.release();     
} }
```

However this one does not, and I have no idea why.

```
// get a user by username/password export async function getUserByUsernameAndPassword(     
    username: string,      
    password_hash: string 
): Promise<User | any> {     
const client=await pool.connect();     
try {         
const resp=await client.query(`             
    SELECT account_id, username, password_hash, email, account_type_id     FROM account                                                 
    WHERE username=$1 AND password_hash=$2`,              
    [username, password_hash]);                 
        const user: User = userConverter(resp.rows[0]);                                 return user;                  
} catch (error) {                  
    console.log(error);         
    //return error.message;      
} finally {         
    client.release();     
} }
```

This is the error I receive from the getUserByUsernameAndPassword():

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'account_id' of undefined at Object.userConverter 
(C:\GitFolder\project1\server\util\converters\userConverter.ts:6:11) at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\GitFolder\project1\server\dao\user-dao.ts:61:36) at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at fulfilled 
(C:\GitFolder\project1\server\dao\user-dao.ts:5:58) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Can supply more code on request

Comment: You might have an error in the client.query call, to have more information you might want to try the following:
```
client
  .query('SELECT XXXX')
  .then(resp => console.log(resp))
  .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```

Comment: Are you sure that the query is actually returning rows? You should probably be checking that `resp.rows.length > 0` before accessing `resp.rows[0]`; ie. something like: `if (respect.rows.length > 0) {
   const user: User = userConverter(resp.rows[0]);
   return user;
} else {
   /* Return something else to indicate username/password mismatch */
  return null;
}`